# Query does not use specified parallel degree

Tags: oracle, performance, parallel-processing, oracle12c, sql-execution-plan

In my Oracle 12c database I want a statement to be executed with parallel degree 2 without the use of a hint. *Note: this is a sample table so there is no improvement in cost or time.*

Execution Plan with parallelism 1

```
PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
-----------------
Plan hash value: 2671887276

-----------------
| Id  | Operation           | Name        | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-----------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT        |             | 1 |   674 | 2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| EVENT   | 1 |   674 | 2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  2 |   INDEX UNIQUE SCAN     | EVENT_PK |    1 |   | 1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
--------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   2 - access("EVENT_PK"='zjmtzhjrth')

Note
-----
   - automatic DOP: Computed Degree of Parallelism is 1 because of parallel threshold
```

Execution plan with hint `/*+parallel(2) */` where DoP works fine

```
PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
---------------
Plan hash value: 2851389777

----------------
| Id  | Operation             | Name        | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time |    TQ  |IN-OUT| PQ Distrib |
---------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT          |         |     1 |   674 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |    |  |        |
|   1 |  PX COORDINATOR           |         |   |   |        |      |    |  |        |
|   2 |   PX SEND QC (RANDOM)         | :TQ10001        |     1 |   674 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |  Q1,01 | P->S | QC (RAND)  |
|   3 |    TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID    | EVENT   |     1 |   674 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |  Q1,01 | PCWP |        |
|   4 |     BUFFER SORT           |         |   |   |        |      |  Q1,01 | PCWC |        |
|   5 |      PX RECEIVE           |         |     1 |   |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |  Q1,01 | PCWP |        |
|   6 |       PX SEND HASH (BLOCK ADDRESS)| :TQ10000        |     1 |   |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |  Q1,00 | S->P | HASH (BLOCK|
|   7 |        PX SELECTOR        |         |   |   |        |      |  Q1,00 | SCWC |        |
|*  8 |     INDEX UNIQUE SCAN     | EVENT_PK |     1 |  |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |  Q1,00 | SCWP |        |
--------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   8 - access("EVENT_PK"='zjmtzhjrth')

Note
-----
   - Degree of Parallelism is 2 because of hint
```

Then I executed the following statements

```
alter system set parallel_degree_policy=MANUAL;
alter table event parallel 2;
```

But when I execute the statement without the hint, it doesn't use parallelism. It doesn't even give me the Note about the DoP in the execution plan.

```
PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
----------------
Plan hash value: 2671887276

-----------------
| Id  | Operation           | Name        | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT        |             | 1 |   674 | 2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| EVENT   | 1 |   674 | 2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  2 |   INDEX UNIQUE SCAN     | EVENT_PK |    1 |   | 1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
-------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   2 - access("EVENT_PK"='zjmtzhjrth')
```

Can anyone tell my why this is not working?

---

Regarding the questions in the comments:

```
PARALLEL_DEGREE_LIMIT=CPU
```

When I set `PARALLEL_DEGREE_POLICY` back to `AUTO` it gives me the note again:

```
Note
-----
   - automatic DOP: Computed Degree of Parallelism is 1 because of parallel threshold
```

The statement I issued for my tests is

```
select * from event where event_pk = 'swdfklwe';
```

Following Cyrille's comment I tried every combination of selected columns and columns in the where clause. The statement just won't use DoP 2 when an index unique scan is used.

```
select event_pk, result form event where event_pk = 'swdfklwe'
select event_pk form event where event_pk = 'swdfklwe'
select event_pk, result form event where event_pk = 'swdfklwe' and result = 0
select event_pk form event where event_pk = 'swdfklwe' and result = 0
```

Comment: why did you set parallel_degree_policy=MANUAL; this disable the parallelism unless you use a Hint in your query.
Set it to auto.

Comment: @CyrilleMODIANO yep, just confirmed it: set degree polity back to auto, now I get the note again: - automatic DOP: Computed Degree of Parallelism is 1 because of parallel threshold

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/REFRN/initparams181.htm#REFRN10310

Comment: what is the value of PARALLEL_DEGREE_LIMIT?

Comment: PARALLEL_DEGREE_LIMIT=CPU

Comment: strange, I can't reproduce the issue on my database, I'll post an answer with my test.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid the hint?  Typically parallel is considered a "good" hint.  It's telling the optimizer something it can't really know (that you want this query to run faster, even at the expense of other users).  Instead of modifying objects would it be better to modify the session: `alter session force parallel query parallel 2;`?

Comment: I cannot use the hint since normally I am not the one formulating and executing the queries, but an application is generating the queries.

Comment: you cant force the CBO in all cases to use parallelism, especially in 12c, why he would use parallel at indexed search? there is no reason for that all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parallel execution is for speeding up queries which traverse a large number of records. It divided the total set of records to be searched into smaller sets and processes multiple sets concurrently. This trades off increased consumption of system resource - primarily CPU - for a reduced total response time.

Your table has a unique index on the searched column. So there  can be only one record which matches `'EVENT_PK"='zjmtzhjrth'`. There is no way parallelism can make that faster.

The optimizer has chosen the most efficient access path to retrieve one row. Be happy that it has.

Why wouldn't

Comment: Please see the note in my post: _Note: this is a sample table so there is no improvement in cost or time._
Plus when I use the parallel hint at least it does some sort of parallelization.

Comment: You asked "why isn't this working"? I have explained why the optimizer doesn't use parallelism for a unique index read. What more do you want?

Comment: You are right, I didn't formulate my question right. The question should have been "How can I get it to work?" But yes, you answered the question I asked.

Comment: But that would be the wrong question. Why do you want to force Oracle to use parallelisation to retrieve one row through a unique key look up? The Optimizer is working correctly right now, so why try to break it?

Answer (score 0):

It work like expected on my side:

```
SQL> create table t1 (id number);

Table created.

SQL> alter table t1 parallel 2;

Table altered.

SQL> explain plan for select * from t1;

Explained.

SQL> @?/rdbms/admin/utlxpls

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 2494645258

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation            | Name     | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT     |          |     1 |    13 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  PX COORDINATOR      |          |       |       |            |          |
|   2 |   PX SEND QC (RANDOM)| :TQ10000 |     1 |    13 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   3 |    PX BLOCK ITERATOR |          |     1 |    13 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   4 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL| T1       |     1 |    13 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Note
-----
- dynamic statistics used: dynamic sampling (level=2)
- Degree of Parallelism is 2 because of table property
```

and here are the parameters I have (all defaults)

```
SQL> show parameter parallel

NAME                                 TYPE        VALUE
------------------------------------ ----------- ------------------------------
containers_parallel_degree           integer     65535
fast_start_parallel_rollback         string      LOW
parallel_adaptive_multi_user         boolean     FALSE
parallel_degree_limit                string      CPU
parallel_degree_policy               string      MANUAL
parallel_execution_message_size      integer     16384
parallel_force_local                 boolean     FALSE
parallel_instance_group              string
parallel_max_servers                 integer     40
parallel_min_percent                 integer     0
parallel_min_servers                 integer     4

NAME                                 TYPE        VALUE
------------------------------------ ----------- ------------------------------
parallel_min_time_threshold          string      AUTO
parallel_servers_target              integer     16
parallel_threads_per_cpu             integer     2
recovery_parallelism                 integer     0
SQL>
```

Comment: You are testing with a full table scan but not with the use of an index unique scan. This might change the behavior.

Comment: same thing here, with and index the parallelism is not used.

Comment: can you share the query you use. From my test it appears that if you query only the indexed column the parallelism is not used but if you select another column and filter by the index then oracle uses the parallelism. I guess it's a matter of cost, oracle decide not to use the parallelism because it will cost more than using parallelism.

Comment: I edited my question (see bottom of post). Unfortunately, parallelism is still not used.

Comment: Compare the cost in the plan for the query not using parallelism and for the same query forcing parallelism with a Hint, what do you get?